# Why do my two click events in my React app run at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, jsx, react-props

I have two user settings options. One is "enable cascading panels", and the other is "include attachments".

I have set up state variables and toggle functions to pass down to the child components so that when I click on either, the parent is able to toggle between the values. The issue is that when I click on either, the other one executes as well. Did I miss a step in setting these up?

#### Parent component data:

##### State:

```js
    constructor(props){
     const userToggleSettings = {
       cascadingPanels: true,
       includeAttachments: true,
       analyticsOptIn: false
     };
    
     this.state = {
       userToggleSettings
     };
    }
```

#### Toggle functions:

```js
toggleIncludeAttachments = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => (
        {
            userToggleSettings:
            {
                includeAttachments: !prevState.userToggleSettings.includeAttachments
            }
        }
    ));
};

toggleCascadingPanels = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => (
        {
            userToggleSettings:
            {
                cascadingPanels: !prevState.userToggleSettings.cascadingPanels
            }
        }
    ));
};

includeAttachmentsClickHandler = () => {
    this.toggleIncludeAttachments();
}

cascadingPanelsClickHandler = () => {
    this.toggleCascadingPanels();
}
```

##### Passing values and functions as props:

```html
<ChildComponent
  attachmentsSwitchHandler={this.toggleIncludeAttachments}
  attachmentsSwitchValue={this.state.userToggleSettings.includeAttachments}
  cascadingPanelsSwitchHandler={this.toggleCascadingPanels}
  cascadingPanelsSwitchValue={this.state.userToggleSettings.cascadingPanels}
/>
```

#### Child component data

##### Setting up click events and values in child component:

```html
<div className='child-component-container'>
    <div className={'user-settings-toggle'}
        onClick={props.cascadingPanelsSwitchHandler}
    >
    <div className={'user-settings-label'}>
            {props.translations.CASCADING_PANELS}
        </div>
    <Switch
        checked={props.cascadingPanelsSwitchValue}
        translations={{
            off: props.translations.off,
            on: props.translations.ON
        }}
        />
    </div>
    <div className={'user-settings-toggle'}
      onClick={props.attachmentsSwitchHandler}
    >
    <Switch
        checked={props.attachmentsSwitchValue}
        translations={{
            off: props.translations.off,
            on: props.translations.ON
        }}
    />
    <div className={'user-settings-label'}>
        {props.translations.ALWAYS_INCLUDE_ATTACHMENTS}
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Demo:

[image]

Could someone clarify what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your toggle functions in such way:

```
 this.setState((prevState) => (
        {
            userToggleSettings:
            {
                ...prevState.userToggleSettings, // ---> added
                cascadingPanels: !prevState.userToggleSettings.cascadingPanels
            }
        }
    ));
```

React doesn't perform a "deep merge", i.e. the nested objects are not merged. Only top level properties are merged.

So the way you had it you were losing whatever was there inside the `userToggleSettings` object, after doing `setState`.